# Permission denied: Linux KVM Share

Tags: kvm, error-handling

When I tried to start the VM I get the following Error (Note, the host is a OpenSUSE Leap 15.3):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 111, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 66, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1281, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1234, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: Internet Error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2022-04-13T10:23:46.817809Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device virtio-9p-pci,id=fs0,fsdev=fsdev-fs0,mount_tag=/home/turbine,bus=pci.7,addr=0x0: cannot initialize fsdev 'fsdev-fs0': failed to open '/home/user/shared': Permission denied
```

My shared folder configuration gives me:

```xml
<filesystem type="mount" accessmode="passthrough">
  <driver type="path" wrpolicy="immediate"/>
  <source dir="/home/user/shared"/>
  <target dir="/shared"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x07" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</filesystem>
```

Comment: "_`failed to open '/home/user/shared': Permission denied`_" - so does the KVM instance have access to this directory?

Comment: The "Permission denied" could be caused by DAC or MAC. For the DAC, that is the access control of Linux. That has been mentioned by @roaima. For the MAC, the common MAC systems in Linux could be Apparmor or SELinux. If the "Permission denied" is caused by Apparmor. In opensuse, the MAC should be apparmor. You can search **AVC** in the **/var/log/audit/audit.log** to see if Apparmor caused the "Permission denied".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results that the directory has to be in a path were every directory before it can be read an searched by any user.

Comment: Not by any user, just the user account that owns and runs the VM

Comment: @ChrisDavies technically all are owned by kvm group, thus in any cause it would have to be owned by the kvm group.